# regular expression us phone number

Tags: php, regex

I have a regular expression that matches the following numbers.

8702431273

973-882-9444 ext 6114

1-223-332-2232

However it does not match.

(+1) 623-975-5296

605-367-7321

How can I modify this to also accept these.

```
^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$
```

Comment: It always helps to know what language you are using when asking regex questions.

Comment: better to simply do a replace of `/[^0-9x]/` to `""` and then split the string on `x`. first part should be 10-11 chars, extension will be the second part if it exists.

Comment: @zzzzBov - That won't work if validation is taking place, or if this is looking for phone numbers embedded in other text.

Comment: Sorry. Its php. The phone number is all by itself. There are just thousands of them, I am checking for valid ones and splitting the extensions into another column.

Comment: @JustinMorgan, it also wont work if the extension isn't separated by an `x` character. If searching is the goal, use a set of common phone number patterns each as their own RegEx, rather than trying to create one behemoth.

Comment: Instead of making that regex even more monstrous, you could consider replacing it with a routine that throws out everything but digits and a few conditions to check the length of that string and whether it starts with a '1'

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you can simply replace this part at the beginning:

```
^(?:1(?:[. -])?)?
```

with this:

```
^(?:\(?\+?1\)?(?:[. -])?)?
```

Or if you want to be strict about the parentheses matching:

```
^(?:(?:\((?=.?1\)))?\+?1\)?(?:[. -])?)?
```

Answer (score 1):

I would incorporate next part to your regexp to match those other telephones:

```
(?:\(\+\d\)\s)
```

It means the plus sign with a digit. Adapt it if can be more digits inside parenthesis or more space after it. Final regexp could be like this.

```
^(?:(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?|(?:\(\+\d\)\s))?([2-9]\d{2})(?:^(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$
```

I divide in lines the part I've changed to adapt new telephone numbers:

```
^
  (?:
    (?:1(?:[. -])?)?
    (?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?
      |
    (?:\(\+\d\)\s)
   )?
([2-9]\d{2})(?:^(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?$
```

In my test it works with the five telephones of your post.